# Delete from table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I still have following error: I want to delete question, but I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`survey_development`.`inquiries`, CONSTRAINT `inquiries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = 217):
```

my controller

```
  def destroy
#    @question.destroy
#    head :ok
#    @question = Question.find(params[:id]) 
    @question.destroy   
    head :ok
  end
```

model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer, :through => :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy

  validates_presence_of :text, :message => "ERROR!"
end
```

I'm stuck with this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like `belongs_to :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy` should be `belongs_to :inquiry`
and in Inquiry model it should be `has_one :question, :dependent => :destroy`

you can't really have :dependent => :destroy on the child object

Comment: and this line is correct "has_one :answer, :through => :inquiry , :dependent => :destroy" ? ///////// i have following inquiry:   belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :respondent
  has_one    :answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the :dependent => :destroy on the Question model because it is the child object of Inquiries.  This is what is invoking the query that is causing your problem.

Comment: thanks for response. But i delete dependents from question model, but still doest work, and i should have write dependent => :destroy somewhere else?  in other models?